# T-sql Replace concat collate

Tags: sql

So I have some code which I'm struggling to understand. I get what the procedure is trying to do as its updating a table etc. However there are some pieces of code which I really don't understand can you please help:

```
LTRIM(REPLACE(llp.son_details, concat(
               cast(llpg.son... as varchar)colate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS),
```

So im not sure what exactly this piece of code means. I believe the LTRIM is trimming the left side of the value in llp.son_dtails and joins (concats) with the cast bit ???

I'm unsure what the whole of the cast line means.

Comment: It looks like you're talking about Microsft SQL Server?  Please specify this clearly in the question and its tags.

Comment: `'''` is suspicious.  It seems possibly you were already in a string literal before this line of code, so we would need the lines before and after this line to give us context.  It is also strange to see the `LTRIM` right next to the (possibly closing) quote, most SQL I'm used to doesn't do automatic concatenation.  That would make `'''LTRIM` an error, or perhaps just really bad coding style.  Either way it makes me want more context (surrounding lines of code) and it raises some concerns.  Also, the parenthesis count starting from `LTRIM(` doesn't match so this may only be part of a line?

Comment: Don't lose heart.  That SQL code looks incredibly difficult.  (well, difficult anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like math, when working with ()'s work inside out. so lets break down the lines; then work last to first.

```
 '''LTRIM(
      REPLACE(llp.son_details, 
       concat(
         cast(llpg.son... as varchar) colate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS), '''
```

So first I assume this isn't a copy paste as this wouldn't compile.  `colate` isn't a function while `collate` is and I don't think `llpg.son...` would be valid.

[What is a collation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) Sorting rules, case and accent sensitivity for your data... but more as well...

[LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) removes leading spaces from a string

[REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a function which replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value. ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

[CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) joins two or more strings together 1 following the next in succession.

[CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) takes a object of one data type and tries to convert it to another data type so llpg.son.... to varchar

[COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) is a set of character encoding rules and influences how information is stored and how data is matched among other things

---

Now that we have some definition's out of the way:

Your line of code is quite incomplete.  What you have provided can not be fully defined as is.  However, with what you have provided; this is what it's doing:

1. casting llpg.son as a varchar in character set defined.  This is just making sure the values being worked with are in a defined collation for comparisons
2. concatenating values together; but you seem to have omitted this part.  so it's combining llpg.son and ... unknown...
3. Replacing all instances of llp.son... and concatenated values in llp.son_details with some unknown value (again you left this part of code out)
4. Removing leading spaces from the final result.